# Dealing with missing data in an one column text file

Tags: python, pandas, awk, text-processing, data-analysis

I have a data set like:

```
IM,XX
IS,YY
SG,3
OTPL,90
TTPL,90
IM,AA
IS,BB
SG,3
TTPL,50
IM,ZZ
IS,CC
OTPL,10
```

Each line contain a `key,value` pair and i need to convert this into a tabular format in order to perform some analysis. The `IM` variable represent the index of a row and the below parameters are the columns. The tricky part for me is to take account the possible missing values. The expected result is:

```
IM  IS  OTPL    SG  TTPL  
XX  YY    90     3    90    
AA  BB  null     3    50    
ZZ  CC    10  null  null
```

"note the null values".

I have a solution but is not so efficient, when the data set is quite big it is't an appropriate way. I use the following strategy:

1. With `awk`, add an extra index for each register (row). It creates a counter `n` and increment it when `IM` appears:

   ```
   $ awk -F, 'BEGIN{n = 0}{ if($1 == "IM"){n += 1} print n","$0}' inputdata.txt
   1,IM,XX
   1,IS,YY
   1,SG,3
   1,OTPL,90
   1,TTPL,90
   2,IM,AA
   2,IS,BB
   2,SG,3
   2,TTPL,50
   3,IM,ZZ
   3,IS,CC
   3,OTPL,10
   ```
2. Next, read the previous result using `pandas`, apply `groupby` by the above indices and creates a new table applying `concat` to `pivot` subtables:

   ```
   In[1]:import pandas as pd
         gb = pd.read_csv("outdata.txt", names = ["id","key","value"]).groupby("id")
         res = pd.concat([df.pivot(index="id", columns='key', values='value') for g, df in gb])
         res
   Out[1]: 
       IM  IS OTPL   SG TTPL
   id                       
   1   XX  YY   90    3   90
   2   AA  BB  NaN    3   50
   3   ZZ  CC   10  NaN  NaN
   ```

The last step is very expensive.

Has anyone had a similar problem? Would be nice solve this only with the command line.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so your goal is to do analysis of these data using only shell commands (i.e., "only with the command line")?  i guess it's not clear to me why your `pandas` solution isn't good enough for you.  how big is your dataset?

Comment: I assume the order of the data is very important, and that a change in order would potentially corrupt the results.

Comment: I think that must be a more efficient way using shell commands or another tools may be. When i use `pandas` as describe above, this operation takes about 10 seconds with a data set of only 1000 rows (in a normal desktop computer) also it consumes a lot of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[UPDATE] pure GAWK solution:**

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
    n = 0
}
{
    if($1 == "IM") {
        n++
    }
    keys[$1]++
    vals[n,$1]=$2
}
END {
    l=asorti(keys, copy)
    printf "id"
    for (i=1; i<=l; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", FS, copy[i]
    }
    print ""

    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        printf "%s", i
        for (k=1; k<=l; k++) {
            printf "%s%s", FS, vals[i,copy[k]] 
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{ .data }  » awk -f prg.awk data.csv
id,IM,IS,OTPL,SG,TTPL
1,XX,YY,90,3,90
2,AA,BB,,3,50
3,ZZ,CC,10,,
```

**[OLD] Pandas solution:**

i think you can just use [pivot_table()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) instead of `groupby()` + `concat()` :

```
In [105]: df
Out[105]:
    id   key val
0    1    IM  XX
1    1    IS  YY
2    1    SG   3
3    1  OTPL  90
4    1  TTPL  90
5    2    IM  AA
6    2    IS  BB
7    2    SG   3
8    2  TTPL  50
9    3    IM  ZZ
10   3    IS  CC
11   3  OTPL  10

In [106]: df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='key', values='val', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=np.nan)
Out[106]:
key  IM  IS OTPL   SG TTPL
id
1    XX  YY   90    3   90
2    AA  BB  NaN    3   50
3    ZZ  CC   10  NaN  NaN
```

or `pivot()` if you don't have duplicates (like in your sample data set):

```
In [109]: df.pivot(index='id', columns='key', values='val')
Out[109]:
key  IM  IS  OTPL    SG  TTPL
id
1    XX  YY    90     3    90
2    AA  BB  None     3    50
3    ZZ  CC    10  None  None
```

the same with `NaN`s instead of `None`s:

```
In [110]: df.pivot(index='id', columns='key', values='val').fillna(np.nan)
Out[110]:
key  IM  IS OTPL   SG TTPL
id
1    XX  YY   90    3   90
2    AA  BB  NaN    3   50
3    ZZ  CC   10  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Excellent solution. It reduce drastically the execution time! :-). The `aggfunc` is not necessary in this case because each `id` has an unique `key`.  Many thanks!

Comment: @ej_f, always glad to help. I've added an AWK solution - could you please check it and give a short feedback - which one is faster?

Comment: @ej_f if the above answer solved your problem (which it appears is the case) be sure to click the checkmark next to the answer, to mark your question as resolved.

Comment: Many thanks @MaxU, you have a good understanding of the `pivot` method, that was the key here. The below post shows the execution times of the solutions. Your `awk` script works pretty well and is the big winner!

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_transform(infile, outfile):
    df = pd.read_csv(infile, header=None, sep=",", names=['id', None])
    df = df.groupby([(df.id == 'IM').cumsum(), 'id']).first().unstack()
    df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
    df.to_csv(outfile, index=None)

infile = "..."
outfile = "..."
my_transform(infile, outfile)

>>> !cat "..."  # outfile
IM,IS,OTPL,SG,TTPL
XX,YY,90,3,90
AA,BB,,3,50
ZZ,CC,10,,
```

The key to this `groupby` is grouping on `(df.id == 'IM').cumsum()`, which means that the occurrence of 'IM' in the first column delineates a new group.  The `my_transform` function takes an input file, transforms it into the desired output, and then saves the result back to a file.

```
df['group'] = (df.id == 'IM').cumsum()
>>> df
      id NaN  group
0     IM  XX      0
1     IS  YY      0
2     SG   3      0
3   OTPL  90      0
4   TTPL  90      0
5     IM  AA      1
6     IS  BB      1
7     SG   3      1
8   TTPL  50      1
9     IM  ZZ      2
10    IS  CC      2
11  OTPL  10      2
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander, definitely you are a pandas master! your idea is a awesome!. The below post shows the execution times of the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to @Alexander and @MaxU for your comments.

The `awk` pure solution had a slightly better performance than `pandas`.
The below result was obtained  with a 35500 rows dataset:

```
# initial solution (pandas + awk)
In [2]: %timeit ej_f_pandas()
1 loops, best of 3: 1min 14s per loop

# maxu's solution (pandas + awk)
In [3]: %timeit maxu_pandas()
1 loops, best of 3: 697 ms per loop

# alexander's solution (pandas)
In [4]: %timeit alexander_pandas()
1 loops, best of 3: 518 ms per loop

# maxu's solution (awk)
In [5]: %timeit maxu_awk()
1 loops, best of 3: 499 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for comparison - it's always interesting to compare different solutions/approaches